# How to bake combined pass via python?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

When I use `bpy.ops.object.bake(type='COMBINED', pass_filter={'DIRECT'})` then it doesn't bake but in blender cycle bake works.

[image]

Why is it so and what is the solution?